# How do put the intermediate results of a recursive function into a list?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, recursion

I wrote a simple recursive function to drop the column with maximum sum until the dataframe has been reduced to the size I want. Here's the code:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,1,1], 
                  'b': [2,2,2,2,2,2], 
                  'c': [3,3,3,3,3,3], 
                  'd': [4,4,4,4,4,4], 
                  'e': [5,5,5,5,5,5]}) 

def recSelect(inputdf):
    if inputdf.shape[1]<=2:
        return inputdf
    else:
        total = inputdf.sum()
        idx = total.idxmax()
        inputdf.drop(idx, axis=1, inplace=True)
        return recSelect(inputdf)

recSelect(s)
```

In this above code, the column 'e' is first removed, then the column 'd', and then 'c'. My question is: how do I properly return the 'idx' and get a list as ['e', 'd', 'c']??

Here's what I have tried but it is not working:

```
idxs = [] # create an empty list
def recSelect(inputdf):
    if inputdf.shape[1]<=2:
        return inputdf
    else:
        total = inputdf.sum()
        idx = total.idxmax()
        idxs.append(idx) # append each idx
        inputdf.drop(idx, axis=1, inplace=True)
        return recSelect(inputdf), idxs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
your_list = list() # the traking list

s = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,1,1], 
                  'b': [2,2,2,2,2,2], 
                  'c': [3,3,3,3,3,3], 
                  'd': [4,4,4,4,4,4], 
                  'e': [5,5,5,5,5,5]}) 

def recSelect(inputdf):
    if inputdf.shape[1]<=2:
        return inputdf
    else:
        total = inputdf.sum()
        idx = total.idxmax()
        your_list.append(idx) # append the dropped idx
        inputdf.drop(idx, axis=1, inplace=True)
        return recSelect(inputdf)

recSelect(s)
print your_list  # there you go!
```

Output `['e', 'd', 'c']`

Comment: Ha, I was so close!

Answer (score 5):

Try to avoid using a global variable - use it in your recursion! Add an extra parameter to the function. This will need to be a list to store the removed column names, but we set the default value to `None` so the list isn't shared between function calls. Initialise the empty list on the first call, and update it each time you remove a column.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,1,1], 
                  'b': [2,2,2,2,2,2], 
                  'c': [3,3,3,3,3,3], 
                  'd': [4,4,4,4,4,4], 
                  'e': [5,5,5,5,5,5]}) 

def recSelect(inputdf, removed=None):
    if not removed:
        removed=[]
    if inputdf.shape[1]<=2:
        return inputdf, removed
    else:
        total = inputdf.sum()
        idx = total.idxmax()
        inputdf.drop(idx, axis=1, inplace=True)
        removed.append(idx)
        return recSelect(inputdf, removed)

vals, removed = recSelect(s)

print(removed)
```

prints

```
['e', 'd', 'c']
```

Comment: I think using the default value of empty list in removed=[] will be a problem when you call the function again later on, since I think the list is only created once (so the list will not be empty during subsequent calls)? http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: @AndreasGrivas great catch! This was exactly what I was trying to avoid with global parameters, and I missed it myself. Updated the answer now (and learned something new!), thanks very much

Comment: @asongtoruin are there any advantages to avoiding the use of global variables? or it is just good practice to do so?

Comment: @chowsai consider the OP's set-up (creating `idxs` externally). Every time we want to call `recSelect`, we need to set `idxs = []` first to make sure we're not carrying over the previously removed columns. This way, all of the important information from applying `recSelect` (the output data and the removed columns) is returned by the function.

Comment: @asongtoruin I have been bitten by that myself, it's a fun debugging situation (especially if you are debugging recursive calls!)

Comment: This is a great answer with lots of insights. I really appreciate it. However, I marked the other answer as accepted just because it is very close to what I had in mind earlier. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @user3768495 yep, If you have to use your code in an OOP fashion, you should definitely follow those insights! : )

Answer (score 1):

If you are ohk with my approach to the problem, why create a recursive function when you can sort the values by sum and can access their index.  i.e

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,1,1], 
              'b': [2,2,2,2,2,2], 
              'c': [5,5,5,5,5,5], 
              'd': [4,4,4,4,4,4], 
              'e': [1,5,5,5,5,5]}) 

sum_order = s.sum().sort_values().index
ndf = s[sum_order[:2]]
li = sum_order[2:][::-1].tolist()
```

Output:

```
ndf
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  2
4  1  2
5  1  2
li
['c', 'e', 'd']
```

When you are in pandas try to avoid loops as much as possible.

Comment: I agree. This piece of code is just a simplified version of what I really need to do. So I still have to use recursion. Thanks anyway!